# How to keep the order of MySQL result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have query that look like this:

```
$query = 'select mcf.*, mc.*, o.*, u.*
          from MyConstructionFile mcf
          inner join mcf.MyConstruction mc
          inner join mc.MyConstructionUser o and o.is_owner = true
          inner join o.User u
          where mcf.id in ('.implode(',', $ids).')';
```

I need the order of result to be exactly like those in array `$ids` but I got result sorted by ID, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add

```
'order by find_in_set(mcf.id, \''.implode(',', $ids).'\')';
```

[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Yes, also OP should look into what `IN` actually does.

Comment: I got error `SQL: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function \'find_in_set\'`

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using ?

Comment: @jcubic: The array must be one parameter: **One** string like this: `'1,2,3,4'`

Comment: Yes I found it in mysql doc, you should update the answer with a string `'order by find_in_set(mcf.id, \''.implode(',', $ids).'\')';`

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
'order by find_in_set(mcf.id, \''.implode(',', $ids).'\')';
```